# Ajax Form needs to be cleared after submission

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajax Form needs to be cleared after submission.
Please how can clear only the text field STUDENT POST with form variable set to postText after ajax form submission
without clearing any other form inputs assuming they are in place.
below is my working ajax form

```
this.postMessage = function(user, text, uname, bb, callback){

var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
var uname=$("#uname").val();
var bb=$("#bb").val();

   $.ajax({
      'url': 'post.php?uname="+uname"',
      'type': 'post',
      'dataType': 'json',
      'data': {
                'id': id,
                'mode': 'post',
                'user': user,
                'uname': uname,
                'bb': bb,
                'text': text
                 },
      'success': function(result){
                 callback(result);
                 },
      'error': function(e){
                 console.log(e);
                 }
                });
        };
};

var c = new Chatter();

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#formPost').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                var user = $('#postUsername');
                var text = $('#postText');
                var err = $('#postError');
                var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
var uname=$("#uname").val();
var bb=$("#bb").val();



 c.postMessage(user.val(), text.val(), function(result){
         if(result){
            text.val('');
         }
         err.html(result.output);
         });
         return false;
        });
```

In the form field, I set it as below.

```
    <form action="post.php" method="post" id="formPost" name="local_storage_form" >


School post:<textarea id="postText" name="postText" class"postText"></textarea><br>


<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: it does not work. the id of the text field is id="postText"

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the id of your field is, but you can add this to your success function:

```
success: function(result){
               callback(result);
               $('#postText').val(''); // might need to change the id...
           },
```

Answer (score 2):

jquery provide if you want to clear an `<input>` or `<textarea>` tag use `.val('')` or its an `<div>` or anything use `.text('')` or `.html('')`.

Answer (score 1):

on Ajax Success Call Just Reset the form

```
document.getElementById("#formPost").reset();
```

Ref :[Reset Form](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)